# Edit a Full HTML node with a Filtered HTML priviledge

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I ran into a strange problem wherein I have an existing node that I saved with Full HTML input format. I then have a user who is only allowed to use Filtered HTML. When the said user logs in and edits the node, he can still see the wysiwyg's full HTML buttons. I have configured different wysiwyg profiles so i was expecting the regular users to just filtered html. What could be wrong?

Comment: What WYSIWYG module/editor are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked all the profiles you have created under wysiwyg ?
Make sure that user's role is not selected in any other profile except the intended one.